# How to set background image in Vue 3 based on image that is uploaded by user

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to set the background image to a url that's on my local machine in Vue 3.

```
<div class="mx-auto placement-image rounded" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + '/Users/mark/Desktop/Images/system76.jpg' + ')' }" >
```

However I'm getting the error below in console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/Users/mark/Desktop/Images/system76.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

It makes sense because the url is supposed to be:

```
/Users/mark/Desktop/Images/system76.jpg
```

and not

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/Users/mark/Desktop/Images/system76.jpg
```

I've looked up some solutions such as using `require` but all the ones I'v seen so far require the image to be in the public folder of the vue project. Where as the images I'm dealing with can be anywhere on a device for local upload.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: What do you mean by local upload? If a user can select an image from their device, you should store the image in the browser via data URL, or by uploading the image to a server and returning the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser doesn't have access to local storage like that. Your options are as follows:

**1. Store the image "in the browser"**

- Using a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)
- Using the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)
- Using the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (for bigger files or multiple files)

**2. Upload the image to a server that will host it for you and get the URL to that image**